# How I will fetch shape files through select options from a website?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select, geoserver

I am trying to configure one select option with shape files into a webmap as follows:
Suppose from the select option 
   if select Country= India,
     then it will show the India map [ shape file is uploaded into Geoserver] into openstreet map and 
     corresponding states it will show in another select option [ like West Bengal, Goa, Gujarat...]
       now from this state list if select state = Gujarat
         then it will show the state boundary [ shape file is uploaded into Geoserver] into openstreet 
         map and corresponding cities it will show in another select option [ like Ahmadabad,..].
and in last one submit button will be there to download some data corresponding that city.

I have created that multiple select options but I can't connect the shape files when I am choosing Country or states.
How will I do it?

Comment: check CQL filters https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Comment: I want to access the shape files from a website through select option.